# Dont want to trigger checkbox when page loads and checkbox is set

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've made a xaml page that contains some checkboxes. When the page loads, i check some isolated storage stuff in the constructor and ticks the checkboxes depending on the settings stored.

But what happends then is that the events are triggered, I dont want them to do that, only on user interaction. How do I stop that?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? you could just use a TwoWay binding, and skip the Checked / Unchecked functions alltogether. Otherwise, you could set a flag for the Checkbox that says ignoreFirstChecked= true. Then when you see the Checked function fire the first time, just set it to false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways:

1. You could set a boolean member variable in your constructor to indicate that the event handlers should not process the events. Reset the variable once you're done assigning the checkbox values.
2. Instead of setting event handlers in XAML you could set them in code behind after you've set the checkbox values.